# HTTP proxy + WCF netMessagingBinding + Service Bus

Tags: azure, wcf-binding, servicebus

Need help with configuring HTTP Proxy while using netMessagingBinding to connect to Service Bus endpoint.
I have an Internet access through the proxy server. When I try to connect to the WCF Service hosted on a worker role on Azure through Service Bus endpoint I get exception that the application cannot connect to the remote endpoint. When I do the same thing through direct internet access everything works perfectly.

Comment: If you want help, you'll need to ask a complete question. Please describe what you want to achieve, any issues you're having, ...

Comment: Thank you Sandrino Di Mattia for your comment, I guess the editted version will be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proxy servers can be tricky depending on the type of proxy. Try changing the settings of your web.config/app.config to enable proxy support:

**Detect automatically:**

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
```

**Define proxy url:**

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" />
      <proxy autoDetect="True" proxyaddress="http://..."/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

**Custom credentials:**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ProxyUser" value="" />
    <add key="ProxyPassword" value="" />
    <add key="ProxyDomain" value="" />
    <add key="ProxyUrl" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
      <module type="CustomProxyCredentials.ProxyBridge, CustomProxyCredentials"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

---

```
namespace CustomProxyCredentials
{
    public class ProxyBridge : IWebProxy
    {
        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get { return new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyPassword"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyDomain"]); }
            set { }
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            return new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUrl"]);
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Connectivity mode:**

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectivityMode.Http;
```

Anyways, configuration should be sufficient in order for this to work correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick: Could not connect to net.tcp://***.servicebus.windows.net:9354/

Comment: After setting the proxy settings, could you also force the connectivity mode to HTTP? (I updated my answer)

Comment: EndpointNotFoundException fires with the following message: "Unable to connect to ServiceBus using HTTP connectivity mode"

Comment: Wait a sec, I think the reason of my problem is the proxy server itself. See the comment of Clemens about this issue at http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/azure/azuremanagement.aspx?ID=40c8df39-c6b1-4f7d-be4c-65642bf14c43
So your solution should work, Sandrino. Thank you!